# How to show parameter values separated by space and comma?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a list from URL parameters

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://www.example.com/page/type=software&sortby=title&Name[]=software%3A%20windows&Name[]=version%3A%2010&sortdirection=asc&Name[]=make%3A%20microsoft'; 
$url_components = parse_url($url); 
parse_str($url_components['query'], $params); 
echo ' The '. implode($params['Name']);
?>
```

but it ends up displaying like

```
software: windowsversion: 10make: microsoft
```

How can I separate the values by a space and comma so it displays as follows?

```
software: windows, version: 10, make: microsoft
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/implode mentions a `$glue` parameter.

Comment: i got it, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

as user mentioned, use php.net/implode $glue parameter.